# Integrated API Console in WSO2 API managers store use unproper port in request URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I created API with WSO2 APi Manager Publisher. Then I subscribed and invoked this API with Integrated API console. All worked OK.

Request URL was like:
https://host,-name:8243/.....

Later I unsubscribed, edited this API a little, published and subscribed.
Now, when I invoke API with API console port number in URL is changed from 8280 to 9443 and, of course, API doesn't work.
When I invoke API in (for instance) Postman with right port number, API works properly.
When I delete API and create new one - API console works properly.
After editing, port is changed again.
Could somebody explain such strange behavior of API Console?

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally. Have you done any configuration changes?

Comment: No. I changed localhost to IP address in carbon.xml and in CORS configuration I replace /* with IP addresses (api-manager.xml). Publisher was opened in one browser and store in another (firefox and chrome). When I edited API, I included a "in" sequence for example. WSO2 APIM manager window was opened to. In firefox in firebug i have seen link:

Comment: I'm sorry, in cookies there was requestedURI cookie with value "../../API context/1.0.0?parameters"

Comment: @TadeusGarsva, Was this solved by removing the cookie?