# Unable to consume REST API in WSO2 API Store

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Have installed the API Manager 1.10.0 on a single machine and got everything running. Created and published API containing Openstack's Keystone URL. However when i try to consume API via API console in API store i get the MANAGEMENT CONSOLE as i response. 
Have looked at the curl sent and the IP is not right.

### Curl request from API Console

[image: Curl request from API Console]

### Keystone API URLs

[image: Keystone API URLs]

Why am i not able to use the API? Why is the Production endpoint in the API overview not used? (it works perfectly fine with a REST Client or even with the same Curl request once i change to IP)

Comment: your images are not there

Comment: Sorry about that, i just added them

Comment: Have a look at [1]. Same question.

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010737/integrated-api-console-in-wso2-api-managers-store-use-unproper-port-in-request-u

Answer (score 0):

When we construct API endpoint URLs we will use following properties defined in API Manager configuration file(api-manager.xml). If you haven't changed anything there then default ports(8280/8243) will appear there. If you can please try this with private browsing window with https session.

And if you replace curl with IP and correct port 8280, 8243 then did it worked as expected?

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
```

Thanks

sanjeewa.